# Организация ресурсов в android application

Tags: java, android, rest, mobile-development

Решил сделать приложение, которое отображает данные по вакансиям разных компаний. Вакансии я получаю в json. Решил сделать отдельную рубрику, где будет список компаний с названием их и картинками. Написал скриптик в котором все это получил, отпарсив нужные ресурсы.

Как мне лучше организовать хранение этих изображений что бы они изначально были в приложении, а не что бы приходилось их парсить при работе? Там почти полторы тысячи картинок объемом общим около 10 мбайт.

Answer (score 2):

Создайте обработчик, который будет сопоставлять картинку соответствующей компании и отображать её в вашем активити, а сами картинки храните в ресурсах приложения.

Например: 
У вас есть ресурсы с картинками под именами, ну например 0001.png, 0002.png и т.д., а ваш скрипт отдает приложению json подменяя внешнюю ссылку на картинку компании ссылкой на ваш файл с картинкой, примерно так

```
    [{"company_pic":"http:\/\/companyname.ru\/ui\/upload\/01fc8bca9852de248af358fb043a6f9e.png",...}]
```

заменяем на

```
    [{"company_pic":"0001.png",...}]
```

Далее парсите json в вашем приложении c локальными ссылками.